# Form to send parameters and close

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the form fields to the action url and then close or a success message appears and I don't know what I can do in the script.

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://exemple.com/clicktocall.php?call_prefix=0&number=NUMBER&name=NAME&city=CITY" method="POST">
    Number: <input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    City: <input type="text" name="city"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" id="btnTest"> Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

I tried some other ways and even had success, but I opened the page with the action return in another tab.

Comment: `window.close()` isn't allowed. Only the script that opened the window can close it.

Comment: _close or a success message appears_ - close what? if you mean the browser then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854246/7918037), if you want a success message after submit, you need may need [`onsubmit` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931828/can-someone-explain-the-difference-between-onsubmit-and-action)